# Android background Image Error

Tags: android, android-image

I get an error when I load a background image before I load another image on top of it. The logcat points to memory error but the background is only 17kb in size.

Here the code in sequence of events

```
package com.firm.armouredassault;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StartNewGame extends Activity {

    MyGame ourView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
    //setContentView(R.drawable.canvas);

        ourView = new MyGame(this);
        setContentView(ourView);

    }




}
```

MyGame.java:

```
package com.firm.armouredassault;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class MyGame extends View {

    Bitmap BTank, TShell;

    public MyGame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.bluetanksm), 10, 200, null);

    }

}
```

Comment: I know the problem is with the line //setContentView(R.drawable.canvas); of the public class StartNewGame extends Activity

Comment: Any idea, how should I load the backgroung images which I use as my background canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the option don't vary when you call BitmapFactory.decodeResource, can't you put the result in a field and reuse this value for every call to onDraw.

I don't think this is an answer or will solve your problem, but I guess your app will feel a lot better no to have to decompress a jpeg everytime you want to display it on screen.

Comment: Tried it but I guess I did not implement it right. Let me try another method as per your suggestion.